# How do I display 3 randomly selected words from a list in set order in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, list, select, random, words

The idea is to generate a random reverse acronym for the acronym 'REG' using a list of words that begin with 'R', 'E' and 'G'. Every time you visit the page that the code is on it should pick a word from each list and place them in the REG order (example: Rodent Echo Ghost, Ronald Evening Garden, etc.)

The result of the code should be displayed as text on a webpage ofcourse.

Optional would be the ability to choose the font family, size and colour.

I searched around for this kind of code but to no avail. Probably also good to mention that I don't have much experience with Javascript at all, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: please create a fiddle and show what r u trying to do ?

Comment: think in term like there is space between each words and `split` it and `concat` first letter

Comment: Here's a lamen's example: https://jsfiddle.net/vn80rzwz/
Sorry for butchering the code, I have no experience with JS.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, but when I put in the code provided here I don't get any visual result. I need it to be displayed as text on a webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to get the string that you want. You can add in each array any number of words that start with the letters..

Then, the variable acron will hold the string that you want. You can inject it wherever you need. Since I do not know what you want to do with it, I can't elaborate.

```
var r=[
    "Rodent",
    "Ronald",
    "Robocop",
];

var e=[
    "Echo",
    "Evening",
    "Everyone",
];

var g=[
    "Ghost",
    "Garden",
    "Green"
]

var randr=Math.floor((Math.random() * r.length) );
var rande=Math.floor((Math.random() * e.length) );
var randg=Math.floor((Math.random() * g.length) );

var acron=r[randr]+" "+e[rande]+" " + g[randg];
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tooxargk/1/)

Comment: the +1 in every rand variable is not neccessary.
Every Array has the indexes 0,1,2
 but Math.floor((Math.random() * r.length) + 1) in this case can be 3

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, but when I put in the code provided here I don't get any visual result. I need it to be displayed as text on a webpage.

Comment: Then add this line `document.getElementById('id').innerHTML += acron;`. This will work if you have a div or an element with the id equal to id. Just replace in this line the id with the id of your element in html where you want to write.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is what I was looking for. I'll post the fiddle of the rough end result. http://jsfiddle.net/uxahzv5w/2/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to split the acronym into letters, and map each letter to an array of words. Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxahzv5w/).

```
function findWordsForAcronym(acronym) {
  var words = {
    'a': [],
    'b': [],
    'c': [],
    'd': [],
    'e': ['Echo', 'Evening'],
    'f': [],
    'g': ['Ghost', 'Garden'],
    'h': [],
    'i': [],
    'j': [],
    'k': [],
    'l': [],
    'm': [],
    'n': [],
    'o': [],
    'p': [],
    'q': [],
    'r': ['Rodent', 'Ronald'],
    's': [],
    't': [],
    'u': [],
    'v': [],
    'w': [],
    'z': [],
    'y': [],
    'z': []
  };

  return acronym.toLowerCase().split('').map(
      function(letter){
        return words[letter][parseInt(Math.random()*words[letter].length)];
      }
  ).join(' ');
}

findWordsForAcronym('REG'); // "Rodent Echo Garden"
```

Comment: Nice and flexible too.  As an extension, you could easily build that word list dynamically from parsing a block of text.  Probably not necessary here, but might be a fun way of reverse engineering arbitrary acronyms :)

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, but when I put in the code provided here I don't get any visual result. I need it to be displayed as text on a webpage.

Comment: @Mark I've updated the answer with a jsFiddle example.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and the help, but I guess I've not been specific enough in the OP, sorry for that.There is no need for anyone to fill in a form. What I'm looking for is a code that displays those randomly picked words from the lists that start with R, E and G in that particular order. The result would be that everytime you'd visit the page that the code is on it would display a different line each time; Rodent Eagle Gary, Racing Echo Garment. The joke behind it is for a community (called REG) to have a different name/meaning  each time you visit their page.

Comment: @Mark The fiddle is an example to see how it works, it can be implemented in any other way.